# How to get the line number or cell number by double-clicking the mouse in the table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to get the line number or cell number by double-clicking the mouse in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the clearest question, but I'm going to assume:

1. You're talking about `JTable`s
2. You're asking for the row index
3. You want to output the row index to stdout

---

You can add a [`MouseListener`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) to a `JTable` that fires on mouse events, and implement the [`mouseClicked`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html#mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent)) method. The `MouseEvent` passed to the `mouseClicked` method has [`getButton`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getButton()) to determine if it was a left click, and [`getClickCount`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getClickCount()) to determine if it was a double click. If so, the `JTable` has [`getSelectedRow`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRow()) to determine the selected row index

It'll look something like:

```
final JTable table;
// ...
table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if(e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1 && e.getClickCount() == 2)
            System.out.println("Current row index: " + table.getSelectedRow());
    }
});
```